Google Cloud db instance automatically deleting database
I have created a db instance in google cloud console. And I created a database named app,but after some hour it is getting auto deleted. Even I created database again and it is getting deleted.

Hi there.
Could you add more information please? Have you checked the logs? Are there any errors?

You can verify on what might cause the issue by running the following query on Logs explorer:
resource.type="cloudsql_database" 
log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity")
resource.labels.database_id="myprojectid:mydatabase"

Furthermore, kindly check as well your billing account if it is still active.
